# Unable to reverse the first difference in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, difference

I have the following data

```
bidopen,bidclose,bidhigh,bidlow,askopen,askclose,askhigh,asklow,tickqty
1.3384,1.33855,1.3387,1.33838,1.33861,1.33878,1.33893,1.33861,694
1.33855,1.33842,1.33865,1.33827,1.33878,1.33865,1.33888,1.33849,814
1.33842,1.33876,1.33883,1.33834,1.33865,1.33897,1.33897,1.33854,459
1.33876,1.33891,1.33899,1.33865,1.33897,1.33914,1.3392,1.33887,626
1.33891,1.33901,1.33918,1.33869,1.33914,1.33922,1.3394,1.33889,771
1.33901,1.33896,1.33907,1.3389,1.33922,1.33916,1.33928,1.3391,451
1.33896,1.33878,1.33906,1.33877,1.33916,1.33902,1.33928,1.33898,552
1.33878,1.3388,1.33889,1.33869,1.33902,1.33902,1.33911,1.33891,421
```

I split the data into X and Y variables. I took the first difference of X and Y variables using
the diff() function in pandas. Now I want to reverse this difference so I used the cumsum() function
in pandas. But it isn't reversing the data back to its original form. It is giving me the same values that
are given by the diff() function. Question how can I reverse the data back after using the diff() function

```
import pandas as pd

dataset = pd.read_csv('/home/mahmoud/Desktop/qdata.csv')

y = dataset['bidclose']
x = dataset.iloc[:, 2:9]

y_diff = y.diff(periods=1)
y_diff = y_diff.dropna()
x_diff = x.diff(periods=1)
x_diff = x_diff.dropna()

y_rev = y_diff.cumsum()
x_rev = x_diff.cumsum()
```

When I use the cumsum() function I want this to be the returned data:

```
bidclose
0   1.33855
1   1.33842
2   1.33876
3   1.33891
4   1.33901
5   1.33896
6   1.33877
7   1.33880
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are on the right track! `cumsum` values sums period to period changes the values have made since the initial value at `index 0`, that is the sum of `diff` at every additional row. You just need to add the initial value to the `cumsum` values to restore dataset's original form.

```
y_rev = y_diff.cumsum() + df['bidclose'][0]
x_rev = x_diff.cumsum().add(df.iloc[0, 2:9])
```

Keep in mind, you have dropped the row at `index 0`, too add it back, you can use [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to add the **row/value** at the beginning.

```
y_rev = pd.concat([pd.Series(df['bidclose'][0]), y_rev])
x_rev = pd.concat([df.iloc[0:1, 2:9], x_rev])
```

Outputs:

```
# y_rev
0    1.33855
1    1.33842
2    1.33876
3    1.33891
4    1.33901
5    1.33896
6    1.33878
7    1.33880
dtype: float64

# x_rev
    bidhigh bidlow  askopen askclose    askhigh asklow  tickqty
0   1.33870 1.33838 1.33861 1.33878 1.33893 1.33861 694.0
1   1.33865 1.33827 1.33878 1.33865 1.33888 1.33849 814.0
2   1.33883 1.33834 1.33865 1.33897 1.33897 1.33854 459.0
3   1.33899 1.33865 1.33897 1.33914 1.33920 1.33887 626.0
4   1.33918 1.33869 1.33914 1.33922 1.33940 1.33889 771.0
5   1.33907 1.33890 1.33922 1.33916 1.33928 1.33910 451.0
6   1.33906 1.33877 1.33916 1.33902 1.33928 1.33898 552.0
7   1.33889 1.33869 1.33902 1.33902 1.33911 1.33891 421.0
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the initial value for the cumsum.

You can try something like this:

```
y = dataset['bidclose']

y_diff = y.diff(periods=1)

y_rev = y_diff.fillna(y[0]).cumsum()
```